# Text within React body won't go away: "w to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`. -->"

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

I don't understand why 'w to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`. -->' is being rendered. Can someone please help me get rid of this. I have ran 'npm run build' but it still appears. Thank y'all.

[image: text-rendered-wont-go-away]

1. ran npm run build - nothing happened to the text
2. went into the build folder and within the .html removed 'w to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`. -->' - text still appears.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this doesn't show when run dev too? Seems to me you left a part of the boiler template comment. Check **public/index.html** and remove it, then build again the production folder. If you remove it from **build folder** you will rebuild it with the comment in. So you need to change the dev files not build files.